# Orderer received bogus greeting from client

Tags: java, sdk, netty, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Using the Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK, I'm failing to construct and deploy the channel. Looks like the problem is that I can't communicate with the orderer whenever I try to set the channel configuration.

```
channel = client.newChannel(channelName, initialOrderer, channelConfiguration, channelConfigurationSignature);
```

Doing this will throw a TransactionException:

```
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel SuperChannel, send transaction failed on orderer orderer.super.com. Reason: UNAVAILABLE
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 000000040000000000000004080000000000000efff1
```

The orderer is up and running but reports bogus greetings:

```
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:19.951 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c1 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xeb)J>\x91\x12\xa8\xe3l\x15c\x13\xbe"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:20.964 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c2 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03drPh__P\x99:|\x1cO\xd3"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:22.442 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c3 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xae\xe2Sod\x9c\"\xe2\xa4\nK\xd4\xf9"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:24.902 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c4 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03o\x87\xa9$\xed:\x93/\"\xeb\xb0\a\xee"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:28.787 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c5 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\x1e\xd27JQ\xf3\xb6j\xeb/\x9c\\\xc0"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:34.603 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c6 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xfa\x93\b\x01\x10>\xfd5z\"\xd6\xf8\xce"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:45.387 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c7 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\x018-\x9d\xde\xf7\xe2g\n\xdc\r\xf8\xa8"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:50:59.725 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c8 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03yU\xe7yH\xa8\xac\xdf\x1c\x85c\xfc\v"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:51:21.874 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c9 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xddN\xe8=4l\xf0\x9cC\xe4K\xb7\xae"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:52:01.472 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1ca transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03P흿\xe7ݎ<K\xac?\xa8("
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:53:06.599 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1cb transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\x87yqd\xfc \xc8U*N.\xedx"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:54:37.862 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1cc transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\x8bL\xac\xc9\r\x93\x98\xfe\xca1\xc3\x1cl"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:56:32.705 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1cd transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xc4\xcdN\xcfS\x95\xb0|B\xe4c\xf0\xb4"
orderer.super.com     | 2017-11-10 09:58:10.790 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1ce transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x96\x01\x00\x00\x92\x03\x03\xc1PǛ\xbe\xdd\xe8,\x13\x0e҇\xf8"
```

And weirdly keeps receiving these every couple minutes, seemingly netty keeps trying after the application has crashed because of the transaction error. This is also the only output I get from orderer.super.com.

For what it's worth, my orderer uses the following properties:

```
ret.setProperty("pemFile", certFile.getAbsolutePath());
ret.setProperty("hostnameOverride", name);
ret.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
ret.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
```

Note that the cert file is a file that does exist and was generated by cryptogen. I've tried regenerating my certificates and orderer.block once again and it doesn't change anything.

If anyone can give my the golden tip, that would be much appreciated. I'm at the second day trying to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you running your orderer node?  Are you sure that TLS is enabled for the actual orderer itself?  Try connecting without TLS from your client and my guess is things will work

Comment: @GariSingh Awesome idea! Actually turning it off in docker-compose.yaml doesn't work, but turning it on got me further. If you write your comment as answer I'll mark it. Thanks!